# React Firebase query startAt() and endAt() not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem with some queries at firebase.

I am trying to make pagination queries work but somehow it always returns the last 5 results instead of results 5-10 with the endAt(10) query. Somehow it seems that its ignoring this query both at `StartAt()` or `endAt()`. Here is my function.

It seems that the `limitToLast()` function is overwriting everything...
I also tried it with the `keys` then I switched to `orderbychild()` to make use of the numbers which is easier for pagination

I appreciate any help

```
fetchNext(){
        this.ref = base.fetch('influencers', {
          context: this,
          state: 'Influencer',
          asArray: true,
          queries: {
            endAt: 10,
            limitToLast: 5,
            orderByChild: 'order',
          },
          then(data) {
            console.log(data);
          this.setState({Influencer: data});
        }
    });
    }
```